# Convert string that is in list format to integer list format

Tags: python

I have a string that is

`string_list = '[15,30]'`

How can I convert it to make it into a list with the values as integers?

Expected Output:

```
integer_list = [15,30]
```

Comment: It depends on what serialization format that string is using. If its straight python, `ast.literal_eval` may work. If its JSON, `json.loads` is a good choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: @stovfl its not a list of strings he wants as a list of ints. Its a single string that he wants to make as a list of ints.

Comment: `i = [int(i) for i in '[15,30]'[1:-1].split(',')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json`, it will load a python object from a string version of that object .
`loads` is for `load str`, if I remember correctly.

```
import json

integer_list = json.loads(string_list)
```

More info on `json`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: upvote for json.loads, much safer than eval stuff

Comment: @ChrisDoyle `ast.literal_eval` does evaluate *"safely"*: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: @ChrisDoyle `ast.literal_eval` is equally safe.

Comment: I always feel dodgy when ever i am writting eval code. something in the back of my mind says dont do this, if your doing it this way there is likely a better design than this :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use ast.literal_eval

```py
import ast

string_list = '[15,30]'
integer_list = ast.literal_eval(string_list)
print(integer_list)
```

Comment: I'm curious, what's the diff between `ast` and `json` ? Is there one better than the other and why ?

Comment: @Xhattam `ast.literal_eval` can evaluate Python literals (it is a safer form of `eval`, which can evaluate arbitrary python expressions). `json` is a, well, JSON parser.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the explanation !

Comment: For a list of integers, json and ast.literal_eval are much the same. There are edge cases like `[1,2,3,4,]` doesn't work in json. ast.literal_eval is python only. If you are sharing this data with other programs, json is the better choice.

Answer (score -1):

What about that ?

```
string_list = '[15,30]'
string_list = string_list[1:]
string_list = string_list[:-1]
integer_list = string_list.split(",")

for item in integer_list :
    item = int(item)
```